# The usage of the preposition "to" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

> Hill grows from having to teach herself new makeup trends and translating them **to** her viewers. ([source](https://www.allure.com/story/jaclyn-hill-palette-line-interview))

I find the use of "to" in this sentence somewhat strange. Wouldn't "for" be a better choice of word?

If the downvote is because I didn't put up enough information or the assumption that I didn't do my homework, I'd like to say that I did a lot of research but couldn't find a way to put together content in a relevant and succinct manner. What I saw as relevant was simply the fact that it was difficult to find examples to support this usage in Google hits save a handful.

Further information from my own comment:

I hit Google Books for examples. What gave me pause is that most of the Google-sourced examples are from the 19th century or even earlier and that it appeared to me the figurative use of the word is more likely in the form of "translate A to/into B" in which B is an end result so to speak.

Comment: The cited text isn't syntactically valid English. Looking at the source, I'd say the writer is very careless and/or not particularly competent in the use of English. But the fact of using ***to*** rather than ***for*** isn't necessarily an error - it's just a less common stylistic choice for the context. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22translate+it+to+me%22) are plenty of written instances of *[Please] [translate it **to** me*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22translate+it+to+me%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually also hit Google Books for examples and saw that same page. What gave me pause is the fact that most of the Google-sourced texts are over 150 years old and that it appears to me the figurative use of the word is more likely in the form of "translate A to/into B" in which B is an end result so to speak.

Comment: @EddieKal  It's fine, but confusing since you expect the construction "*from* A *to* B" but end up with something else.  You have to read the sentence a few times before you can be sure what it means.

Comment: @Andrew: I just looked at the text again, but I still can't see any way to parse it so it could be called "valid". Please enlighten. I could *almost* see a valid sentence if ***translating*** were changed to "bare infinitive" ***translate***, but even then it hardly seems syntactically credible to me.

Comment: The sentence is, at best, unidiomatic. Better would be *Hill grows **by teaching** herself . . .* (Which is where the real problem lies. The use of **to** at the end is fine. While *for* and *to* do have different subtle meanings, each of which could be more appropriate in context, neither is clearly *better*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The *translating* is in sequence, thanks to the *and*, with *having* rather than *to teach*; that's a grammatically reasonable way to read it.

Answer (score 1):

While the sentence has issues in terms of seeming like natural, well-formed text - and possibly with being grammatical in terms of normal usage - the use of *to* rather than *for* there isn't one of them.

True, there are people who insist that the preposition *to* should only be used for adverbials that modify *translate* if they are indicating the language that the translation is into (some authorities prefer *into* for that use, and advise against using *to* in order to avoid confusion). However, that insistence is contrary to actual usage by native speakers. I suspect that this is because we use *to* and *for*, when referring to a person, for slightly different meanings.

If you translate something *for* someone, you are doing it **for their benefit** or **at their request**. If you translate it *to* someone, you are **delivering the translation directly to them**. The difference is subtle, but there. You can see the same thing with *explain* - the difference, albeit subtle, between explaining something *for someone* and *to someone*.

However, there's another issue here. Does *translating* here actually mean taking something in one language and rendering it in another? Nothing I've found, at the source or from some other research, suggests that this is what we're talking about. So it could be figurative, or it could be [a different sense of the verb *translate*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/translate). The second sense at Oxford is arguably the original sense, in fact, with the sense related to language originally being a figurative use. Thus, it could be a (slightly confusing) use of *translate* where one might use *convey* or *transmit*.

Comment: Actually I read the sentence as a figurative use of translate, employing the definition "to express in more comprehensible terms : EXPLAIN, INTERPRET" ([MW 1c(2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate)). And that is why I found the line in question unnatural. I would be perfectly happy with _"Can you translate this to me?"_ My research on Google seems to suggest that the vast majority of sentences with figurative _translate_ are in the form of _translate A to/into B (result)_

Comment: @EddieKal All I can say is that, as a native speaker, I find nothing strange about it and wouldn't be surprised to see it.